# How do I use AWS CLI to list all instances with name, state, instance size and AZ in the same line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How do I use AWS CLI to list all instances with name, state, instance size and AZ in the same line?

I got close with this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[], Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceType,State.Name]' --output text
```

But that outputs the instance name below the rest.  I want to keep them on the same line so I can copy to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change `Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]` to `Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0]`; I think it's because `Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]` returns an array which the text output format doesn't know how to put on a single line, piping to `[0]` extracts the (single) element out for you. So your full query should be :

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0], Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceType,State.Name]' --output text
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to scratch your eyes out with the piping syntax, consider this simple shell workaround:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[], Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceType,State.Name]' | \
while read Zone Type State ; do 
   read Name
   echo "$Name $Zone $Type $State"
done
```

Assuming that the original command returns 2 lines like these for each machine:

```
my-ec2-host-xyz
us-east-1d      t2.micro        running
```

The output of the above script will be:

`my-ec2-host-xyz us-east-1d t2.micro running`

This hack is easily understood and can readily be adapted to --output text of any complexity.